# Facebook API campaign insights action_values

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Calling the Facebook campaign insights API, I want to retrieve "action_values".

I've tried from PHP code and from tool explorer using an url like this:

XXXXXX/insights?fields=action_values

but this is the result (action_Values not appear in response)

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "date_start": "2021-02-25",
      "date_stop": "2021-02-26"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MAZDZD",
      "after": "MAZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you verify that this is not a valid answer? Maybe the words "action_values" are simply not emitted and the result is correct?

Comment: action_values is a valid field: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/insights/.... Reading this document parameters like actions and cost_per_actions return correctly. I would like to read a good reason for this XD

Comment: how solved this problem? I'm encounting same problem